# Retrieve multiple keys from ListBox populated with Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox populated with days of the week via a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> Days()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> day = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    day.Add(1, "Sunday");
    day.Add(2, "Monday");
    day.Add(3, "Tuesday");
    day.Add(4, "Wednesday");
    day.Add(5, "Thursday");
    day.Add(6, "Friday");
    day.Add(7, "Saturday");
    return day;
}


private void SetDays()
{
    listBoxDays.DataSource = new BindingSource(Days(), null);
    listBoxDays.DisplayMember = "Value";
    listBoxDays.ValueMember = "Key";
    listBoxDays.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The listbox is set up for multiselect, and I would like to grab all of the dictionary Keys from the selected items...  Whenever I try to loop through I only get the value of the first key selected for the entire collection.

```
private void GatherDays()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    foreach (var item in listBoxDays.SelectedItems)
    {
        list.Add((int)listBoxDays.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

It is easy to get a single selected item's key but I am having a very difficult time trying to get multiple selected.

Comment: What kind of application are you targeting ? ASP.Net, WinForm ?

Comment: just curious, what is the difference between `listBoxDays` and `listBoxBuildDays`?

Comment: This is for a winform application, and please excuse the typo on listboxdays & listboxbuilddays...   they are the same thing.

Comment: have you tried [SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) or even [SelectedIndecies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx) indstead of `Selectedvalue`?

Comment: @Chancea  I have, but I was using the dictionary because I wanted the to start with 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `GatherDays` method like:

```
private void GatherDays()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in listBoxBuildDays.SelectedItems)
    {
        list.Add(item.Key);
    }
}
```

Or you can shorten your code using LINQ like:

```
List<int> list =listBoxBuildDays.SelectedItems
                    .OfType<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
                    .Select(r => r.Key)
                    .ToList();
```

Currently the issue is due to:

```
 list.Add((int)listBoxDays.SelectedValue);
```

`SelectedValue` represents the selected value at lowest index in `Items`.

See: [ListControl.SelectedValue Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If multiple items are selected, the value of the selected item with
>   the **lowest index** is returned. If no item is selected, an empty
>   string ("") is returned.

That is why you are only seeing a single value in your list.

**One more thing to add.**

You can use [`DayOfWeek` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your work instead of dictionary like:

In `SetDays`

```
private void SetDays()
{
    listBoxBuildDays.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
    listBoxBuildDays.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

and in `GatherDays`

```
private void GatherDays()
{
    List<int> list = listBoxBuildDays
        .SelectedItems.Cast<DayOfWeek>()
        .Select(r => (int) r)
        .ToList();
}
```

*But the only thing different would be number (index), this starts with `0`, instead of `1` like in your dictionary.*

Comment: Habib, thankyou so much!  I was stuck on this one for awhile but was not aware of "KeyValuePair" until now.   Works great!   Thanks again!

Comment: @Mikem, just added another option to use `DayOfWeek` enumeration instead of your own dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the addition Habib!  In my case I wanted my days to begin with 1, which is why I went with the Dictionary to avoid zero-based index.